# One-time QML Column spacing override

Tags: javascript, qt, layout, qml, spacing

I use QML Column layout, but I'd like to disable (or decrease) spacing between two elements only. Between the rest the spacing should be left alone.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decreasing is difficult, but increasing the space between two adjacent items is easy: just insert an empty `Item` between them with the needed additional vertical space (minus the amount of one extra regular spacing, of course) as `height`. Don't forget to also set a non-zero `width` or otherwise the item won't be taken into account for the layout calculation.

With no spacing set for the `Column` itself you can achieve this way every spacing configuration possible. This is obviously a bit hacky, but there is no other way.

Comment: You can set the height to a negative value to decrease the spacing too.